# How to prefill a form with post data in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to populate a form in the main page which on being submitted opens a lightbox which contains another form .

I was planning to submit the form using Post as that seems to be the only way I can define which iframe to open in the lightbox .However my question is that how do I pre-populate the second form with the first forms data when I use the submission as POST

I am using ASP.NET and C#

I apologize for the naive question but I am still playing around with ASP.NET

Answer (score 2):

We dont have many details on items such as - is there a redirect? whats the second form? how are you handling controls.. etc

Check this out to start. If you really need to send values across *separate* requests there are various ways to do this, but specify if this is what you are trying to do.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Form` collection in the `Request` object on the second form. The name in the collection is the same as the name in the name/value pair you're using in the post.

```
TextBox1.Text = Request.Form["someName1"];
TextBox2.Text = Request.Form["someName2"];
```

Etc.